# Writing a Workflow rule

Tags: workflow, user

I am new to Salesforce and I am asked to write a `Workflow` to capture the last time a User was deactivated. What steps do I need to take to create such a `Workflow`?

Answer (score 2):

**Steps**

1. Navigate to `Setup` > `Create` > `Workflows & Approvals` > `Workflow Rules`.
2. Click <kbd>New Rule</kbd>.
3. Select `Object` > `User`.
4. Select `Evaluate the rule when a record is:` > `created, and every time it's edited`.
5. Under **`Rule Criteria`**, select `Run this rule if the following` > `formula evaluates to true`.
6. Enter this formula: `AND(NOT(IsActive), ISCHANGED(IsActive))`
7. Click <kbd>Add Workflow Action v</kbd> > `New Field Update`.
8. Select the field to update.
9. Populate `Use a formula to set the new value` > `NOW()`.
10. Click <kbd>Activate</kbd>.

**Explanation**

Step 4 - You can only check for changes to a field if you evaluate on every edit.
Step 6 - You want to make sure the user is deactivated, and that it was not before.
Step 8 - You just need to time stamp when it happened.

Comment: Adrian, I am receiving the following error after step 5.."Function ISCHANGED may not be used in this type of formula" Can you please let me know what is the mistake from my side.

Comment: Adrian, that works. Thanks for patiently answering my question and helping me out.